# AnalyzingInfixSuggester giving one suggestion

Tags: solr, lucene, autosuggest

For the same dictionary which give multiple suggestions for AnalyzingSuggester, it is giving only **one single suggestion** for AnalyzingInfixSuggester.

Following are my configurations:

```xml
<!-- AnalyzingInfixLookup suggest component (default)-->
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="infix_suggest_analyzing">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">infix_suggest_analyzing</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
  <str name="storeDir">infix_suggest_analyzing</str>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>

  <!-- Suggester properties -->
  <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
  <str name="field">debug_field</str>
  <str name="sourceLocation">${solr.solr.home}/${solr.core.name}/dictionaries/dictionary.txt</str>
</lst>

  <!-- specify a fieldtype using keywordtokenizer + lowercase + cleanup -->
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">debug_type</str>
</searchComponent>

<!--  Infix analyzing handler (default) -->
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/infix_suggest_analyzing">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">infix_suggest_analyzing</str>
  <!-- NOTE: if this is false, results are alpha-ordered, not by weight! -->
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>infix_suggest_analyzing</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

My schema:

```xml
<fieldtype name="debug_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1000">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
 </fieldtype>


<!-- basic text field -->
<fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>

<fieldtype name="phrase_suggest" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
          pattern="([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}]*[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}\_]+:)|([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}])+"
          replacement=" " replace="all"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Any idea why it is suggesting only one suggestions? Im using solr 4.6 and the dictionary has the format of . This works perfectly with AnalyzingSuggester.

Comment: When you consider that by default there is a minimum prefix length of 4 on that suggester, does it make sense?  Also, if it works perfectly with `AnalyzingSuggester`, why aren't you using that?  Whether or not your results are correct, the two don't do the same thing.

Comment: I saw the code, DEFAULT_MIN_PREFIX_CHARS is the minimum chars after which PrefixQuery is used. Giving a query of length greater than 4 does not effect the result.
I am not using AnalyzingSuggester as I want to use the Infix feature of AnalyzingInfixSuggester. That is why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it answers your question, but here is my working example.

I'm using `Solr 4.6.0`.
My dictionary is based on a `string` field: `suggest_field`. The filed type `suggest_string` is used only by the suggester, note that it uses

```xml
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
```

the infix feature **does not work with `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory`**.

*schema.xml:*

```xml
<field name="suggest_field" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="suggest_string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

*solrconfig.xml:*

```xml
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="field">suggest_field</str>

        <!-- Minimum frequency of terms to consider when building the dictionary
        0 == all terms -->
        <float name="threshold">0.0</float> 
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggest_string</str>

        <bool name="exactMatchFirst">true</bool>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```